# Exclude list of complex objects from IQueryable by two properties

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have two types:

```
public class DocumentEntityItem 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Type { get; set; }
}

public partial class DocumentEntityToFilesCategory
{
    public int FilesCategoryId { get; set; }
    public int CmsFileId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Sorder { get; set; }
    public string DocumentType { get; set; }

    public virtual FilesCategory FilesCategory { get; set; }
}
```

And I got the list of `DocumentEntityToFilesCategory` type. I want to exclude from this list another list of type `DocumentEntityItem` by two properties - `CmsFileId` and `DocumentType`, so I tried to write some code like:

```
List<string> mainList  = new List<string>()
{
   "1/document",
   "1/link",
   "2/document",
   "3/link"
};
    var documentToCategoryItems= DB.DocumentEntityToFilesCategory.Where(z => z.FilesCategoryId == categoryId);
    List<DocumentEntityItem> documentEntityItems= mainList.Select(z => new DocumentEntityItem
    {
       Id = Int32.Parse(z.Split("/")[0]),
       Type = z.Split("/")[1]
    }).ToList();
    var toDelete = documentToCategoryItems.Where(z => !documentEntityItems.Any(c=>c.Id==z.CmsFileId&&c.Type==z.DocumentType));
```

But, `List.Any()` supports only primitive types.

Comment: "List.Any() supports only primitive types" what?

Comment: @Blindy I got an error "only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context" on .Any() method

Comment: I don't believe you, show me an example code that generates that error on `Enumerable.Any()`.

Comment: Well, `Any()` is used to determine if an enumeration contains any elements (or an element that fulfills a certain condition). So, of course, you need an enumeration type.

Comment: `documentEntityItems` may not be of an enumeration type.

Comment: @Xaver sorry, documentToCategoryItems is not list, It's a IQueryable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll start by saying that your conclusion is flat out wrong, and the error message you mentioned in your comments either does not exist or is related to something completely different. Here's a fiddle showing your code compile as written without any problems: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Aor3rH

You should probably know however that even if it does compile, the quality of the code is extremely low, because you're doing an `O(n^2)` algorithm to implement your exclude (difference) operation, instead of an `O(nlogn)` operation as you should be able to trivially do. Also this specific algorithm is part of the `morelinq` nuget package under the name `ExceptBy`, so you don't even need to implement it correctly, just reference it and use it!

Comment: Your right. My problem was that documentToCategoryItems was IQueryable , not list. After converting It works well.

Comment: If you're working with `IQueryable` (ie a modern EF Core version), you can also use `Any` like this to do the exclusion on the server side and you only get the correct results